# How can I interface an Android app with SQL Server?

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, web-services, asp-classic

This is my problem:

I have to make an Android app that recover some data from an existing database situated on a Microsoft [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) installation on [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003). I don't know so much about server-side programming languages, so I'm searching on the Internet, and I've found that I have to use a Web Service between my app and the [ASP Classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) page that connect to the database.

I also found that I have to use [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) to send data to the server with my app, using the ksoap2 library on Android, and I found how to configure it on the client side. But I can't find how to configure the WebService and which format is better for interfacing my app and the ASP Classic page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy, actually. All what you need is to create a webservice which will display the results in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. Then you need to run an HTTP request from your Android app in order the get a JSON array containing JSON objects and then you will have your data from your database.

For example: the webservice will have a function written in ASP with a SELECT statement. Before your return the result, you need to encode it in JSON. Check out *[JSON Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx)* (MSDN).

The Android app will connect to the web service link and simply retrieve the JSON encoded data. I'll put you in the right way. You just use a snippet like this one to get data from the web service:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

client.get("http://yourwebservice.aspx", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(response);
        for(int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
            // Do your things...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok thank you for reply. But...you used client.get("http://yourwebservice.aspx" ...
is ".aspx" compatible with a classic ASP page ? Because I found many examples with aspx pages but I'm not sure that it was compatible with.

_I pushed "send" button for error sorry :/_

Comment: Awesome ! I'll try and I will reply the result. Thank you so much Nadir :)

Comment: your welcome, can you accept the answer if it put your in the right way ?

Comment: Sure, now I upload on the server a aspx file to try.. :) fingercrossed

Comment: what's up ? did you get it ?

Comment: I have some question Nadir. Surfing the web I saw that I have to install the SOAP Toolkit 3 on the server to generate the .wsdl and the .wsml files. Is that true ?

And I wanna ask you if a code similar to this can be ok to consume from android:

`<%
Set SoapClient = Server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient")
SoapClient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True
SoapClient.mssoapinit "http://localhost/listener/AccessService.wsdl","AccessService","DataSoapPort","http://localhost/listener/AccessService.wsml"
risultato = SoapClient.rsResult("SELECT Descrizione FROM tblProdotti")
`

Comment: don't you have a IIS Server ?

Comment: @PierpaoloErcoli Nadir is making a lot of assumptions about your setup, just to clarify Classic ASP is not compatible with ASP.Net (which is the `aspx` extension example Nadir gave you).  You would use the same approach but with a Classic ASP page (if that is what you are using) to return the JSON data.

Comment: @NadirB Just for clarity [tag:asp-classic] is not the same as [tag:asp.net]. When you use the term *"ASP"* you are referring to ASP.Net.

Comment: Lankymart thnx for clarification, @PierpaoloErcoli check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec

Comment: check the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec

Comment: @Lankymart oh now all is more clear.. ok I will call it asp-classic sorry guys

Comment: @NadirB already seen but I don't have Visual Studio and I can't install it :/

Comment: sorry want to give this one https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/

Answer (score 0):

Create a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) web service in [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Apache_License_2.0_release) or [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation). Web API will communicate with the database and your Android application with communicate with the web service.

Comment: But with a RestFull web service I can't use ksoap2 library that it seem to be very easy to configure from android.. Right?

Comment: In android client no need to use ksoap2, you can form a Json object with required data and post it to some specific URL in your webservice (through HTTP client in URL). In webservice, you need to process that data and store it in the database.  For converting Json object to Java object in Android client, you can use [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: it seems to be cool. :) but which extension will have the webservice? wsdl, aspx, asp, asmx ??

Comment: You can configure the webservice end points without any extension at all.